# Using Firebase Authentication with mongodb database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, mern

I am trying to wrap my head around this so here goes..  Can I use firebase authentication with mongodb?  I am trying to build a sort of message board using the mern stack and I hate dealing with authentication.   How would I store the user in mongodb and have linked to for example a certain comment that was left by them?  I just need some direction or possible some alternatives.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is just a completely basic answer, many people do have a lot more knowledge about this than me. But, to answer your question: yes, you can use firebase authentication with MongoDB. When a person is making a user on your page, you can easily make a document inside MongoDB where all the user's data is stored. When you want to link your user to a comment, your database may look something like this:

```
Comments (collection) - 'random id' - user: 'firebase uid', comment: 'Hello world!', timestamp: '6th of March, 20:24' (document)
         - 'random id2' - user: 'firebase uid', comment: 'Hello StackOverflow!', timestamp: '2nd of March, 23:59' (document)
```

You could of course design your database otherwise, and there is 100% a much more effective way, but this will hopefully give you a direction to where to start.

I assume you somewhat know how to use MongoDB and Firebase Authentication.

Comment: This makes complete sense to me, Thank you.   You know sometimes how you just can't visualize how to do something,  I was going through that.  I appreciate the feedback

Comment: Glad I could help. We all have some times when we just don't know where to get started, and therefore other people are there to help. Good luck with your project!